# Apache 2.4 strip query parameter and add that as a header

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, apache2.4

I have the following url -

http://ip:8080/dashboard/db/testdash?id=add&t1=abc

I want to strip off t1 from the url and add that as a header to my proxy request. I have working reverse proxy conf and I want to intercept this url strip the t1 parameter and add that as header which will be sent to the destination

I have the following configuration for my virtual host listening on 8080

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)t1=(.*)
>>>Need to add the rewrite logic here
>>>Add rewrite conf here change url to /dashboard/db/testdash?id=add

//Add the request header 
>>>RequestHeader set X-T1 "value of the query parameter"

//Proxy 
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass "/" http://localhost:3000/
ProxyPassReverse "/" http://localhost:3000/

Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "*"

# Added a rewrite to respond with a 200 SUCCESS on every OPTIONS request.
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]
```

I am completely new to httpd so don't how to do this!

Answer (score 0):

- remove `ProxyPass` since we want to use the variable
- add `RewriteRule (^/.*) http://localhost:3000/$1?%1`

  Note, this matching is not sufficient if the URL can ever have more keys at the end! A more robust regex would only gobble up the t1 value by capturing up to &.  e.g. `^(.*)t1=([^&].*)(.*)` then substitute `%1%3`
- Add a quirky empty section to make up for the removed `ProxyPass`

```
<Proxy http://localhost:3000/ >

</Proxy>
```